# class path resource [application.yml] cannot be opened because it does not exist Maven, SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have created multimodule project with `SpringBoot` and `Maven`.

I have changed `application.properties` file to `application.yml` file.

`Application.yml` file is inside `src/main/resources`

In service class, I am trying to do

```
@Value("${keycloak.realm}")
private String REALM;
```

The first error that I have is:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'keycloak.realm' in value "${keycloak.realm}"
```

When I place `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.yml")` annotation to same service that is calling `@Value` annotation I am getting following error:

```
class path resource [application.yml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Here is service class:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.yml")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KeyCloakServiceImpl implements KeyCloakService {

    @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
    private String REALM;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource

Comment: Thank you! I just implemented it and it works great! Thank you! You saved my day! :) Can you please put it as a more descriptive answer, so others can have it as well, also for me to be able to accept your answer! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `@PropertySource` doesn't look for yaml files. To do it, you have to tell `@PropertySource` to load a yaml file with the `factory` property :

```java
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:foo.yml", factory = YamlFactory.class)
public class SomeClass() { }
```

Where an implementation of `YamlFactory.class` can be :

```java
public class YamlFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) 
      throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }
}
```

For more information : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource